# EC2 instances in private subnets cannot access amazon repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, connectivity, private-subnet

I am trying to create ECS cluster and I have manually built VPC with 3 public and 3 private subnets. All 3 public subnets have IGW attached to them with 0.0.0.0/0 and all 3 private subnets have NAT Gateways attached in route tables with 0.0.0.0/0. Each of 3 NAT Gateways are in each public subnet respectively.

I have already created another ECS Cluster with the same CloudFormation template that I am trying to use now and everything worked fine.

I have compared settings between 1st and 2nd VPC (failing one) and all settings (IGW, NAT Gateway, Route Tables, NACLs, SG) are same of course IPs are adjusted to the IP of 2nd VPC. When I try to create ECS in 2nd VPC (failing one) EC2 instances in private subnets fail to connect to Amazon repository and subsequently the whole stack is rolled back because the signal from EC2 instances is never being sent to Auto Scaling Group.

Afterwards I have checked the system logs from EC2 instances and they are not able to install amazon agent. Here is excerpt from logs:

```
Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:config' at Mon, 20 Aug 2018 06:38:04 +0000. Up 10.06 seconds.
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds')
Aug 20 06:38:20 cloud-init[2116]: util.py[WARNING]: Package upgrade failed
Aug 20 06:38:20 cloud-init[2116]: cc_package_update_upgrade_install.py[WARNING]: 1 failed with exceptions, re-raising the last one
Aug 20 06:38:20 cloud-init[2116]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module package-update-upgrade-install (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_package_update_upgrade_install' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_package_update_upgrade_install.pyc'>) failed
Generating SSH2 ED25519 host key: [  OK  ]

Starting sshd: [  OK  ]

ntpdate: Synchronizing with time server: [  OK  ]

Starting ntpd: [  OK  ]

Starting sendmail: [  OK  ]

Starting sm-client: [  OK  ]

Starting crond: [  OK  ]

Starting cgconfig service: [  OK  ]

Starting docker:    .[  OK  ]

Starting cloud-init: Cloud-init v. 0.7.6 running 'modules:final' at Mon, 20 Aug 2018 06:38:25 +0000. Up 29.91 seconds.
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-i85tqq/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm: amazon-ssm-agent-2.3.13.0-1.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-i85tqq/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds')
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
[   53.291581] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   53.297948] Bridge firewalling registered
[   53.304776] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (65536 buckets, 262144 max)
[   53.318481] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[   53.510300] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[   53.515251] Netfilter messages via NETLINK v0.30.
[   53.518920] ctnetlink v0.93: registering with nfnetlink.
[   53.688086] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5000 milliseconds')
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was
12: Timeout on http://repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list: (28, 'Connection timed out after 5001 milliseconds')
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 9: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init: No such file or directory
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 10: /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal: No such file or directory
Aug 20 06:39:13 cloud-init[2286]: util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [127]
Aug 20 06:39:13 cloud-init[2286]: cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
Aug 20 06:39:13 cloud-init[2286]: util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.pyc'>) failed
```

I have checked NACL, for Inbound and Outbound everything is set to 0.0.0.0/0 and ALLOW.

For the 1st VPC I am using ECS optimized AMI and **t2.large** (no issues whatsoever) and for 2nd **c5.xlarge** (causing issues).

What could be still causing EC2 to being unable to reach Amazon repository?

### Edit

So later on I found out 2nd VPC has S3 Endpoint attached to it. After a little bit more research I found a nice post on LinkedIn stating:

> The Amazon Linux repositories are hosted on S3 and because of this
>   it's necessary to allow access to it in the S3 endpoint policy.
>
> So when you fire up yum it uses the magic of local DNS trickery to
>   route to the internal S3 endpoint

I went on to update my CloudFormation template and added additional policy to the LaunchConfiguration below, but that did not help:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com",
                "arn:aws:s3:::repo.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

And Endpoint Policy looks like this:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Principal": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally after exploring all the sections of AWS console, I have found out what was causing the issue. As already stated in my update of the original post, when Endpoint is attached to VPC the EC2 will try to resolve packages and repositories internally. I went and checked every setting of Endpoint and found out that only route tables of Public Subnets where added to the Endpoint and after I have added Private subnets as well, the EC2 instances could reach the packages and repositories.

[image]

Comment: I'm running into a very similar problem, yum updates are failing on ECS optimized Amazon Linux hosts deployed in a private subnet. Every other yum install works fine. The only thing is, we are associating our private subnet route table to the S3 Gateway endpoint. Our public subnets are not associated with the S3 endpoint and adding them does not solve our issue here.

Comment: Ok, just figured this out, we setup yum.conf to use a proxy as part of the security posture in our env's. Adding proxy=_none_ to amzn2-core.repo and amzn2-extras.repo in /etc/yum.repos.d/ fixed the problem for me. This allows the request to route across the S3 VPC Endpoint correctly instead of confusing the proxy we have in place with an internal IP address resolved to S3.